# How to stop React HTML escaping quotes in test with testRenderer?

Tags: reactjs

When I use this test it almost works

```
it('renders HTML correctly', () => {
  const result = TestRenderer.create(
  <NavButton step="2" direction='prev' />)
  expect(result).toEqual('<button className="btn btn-prev" onClick={[Function onClick]} type="button">Prev</button>');
});
```

but I get

```
Tests.test.js
FAIL  src/components/NavButton.test.js
expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality
Expected: "<button className=\"btn btn-prev\" onClick={[Function onClick]} type=\"button\">Prev</button>"
Received: <button className="btn btn-prev" onClick={[Function onClick]} type="button">Prev</button>
```

The problem is that **my** string in the test (not the result string) is having its quotes (") escaped with \"

So the fix is NOT to escape the quotes with a backslash (they are not appearing in the result, they are apeearing in my comparison string) - the problem is to stop their being a backslash in the first place.  Maybe there a method to do this. Or make the result escape them somehow.

I tried switching quote types with double quotes around the outside but then I had a similar problem with inside quotes needing to be escaped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TestRenderer.create` does not return a string, but a testRenderer instance, so you’re comparing 2 different types objects.

Check the documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/test-renderer.html